# Strange behavior of c_str?

Tags: c++

I have a below code snippet. I am expecting that the output will be `mystring`, but strangely it outputs junk characters.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    string s1("mystring");

    const char* s2 = s1.c_str();

    s1 = "Hi there, this is a changed string s1";

    cout << s2 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

(1) 
My initial thinking was that `c_str` takes care of allocating sufficient memory
to hold `s1` and returns address of that memory chunk which gets assigned to `s2`, and from here on `s1` and `s2` start out independently.

(2) 
but when I assigned `s1 = "Hi there ..... "` my thinking in (1) proved to be wrong. Somehow, `s1` is still influencing `s2`.

(3) 
When I commented out `s1 = "Hi there .... "` line, everything works fine, i.e., `mystring` gets printed consistently.

(4) 
I am not really convinced about my claim in (1) that `c_str` is allocating memory to hold `s1`, because if that is the case we will have to handle freeing that memory chunk via `s2` pointer which we don't do. So I am not sure about that.

Please help me explain for this strange behavior.

Comment: `s2` does not own the string. UB ensues.

Comment: *but strangely it outputs junk characters.* -- I see nothing strange about this.  This is no different than holding onto a pointer that points to dynamically allocated memory, the memory gets freed, and then who knows what you will be pointing to if you attempt to use the freed pointer.

Comment: std::string will normally have to re-allocate the memory to store the string content.  Not always, it does tend to have a micro-optimization for very short strings.  But you have good evidence of that re-allocation being done, s2 is now a dangling pointer.  You also have good evidence that you use a heap allocator that intentionally scrubs deleted heap blocks, that is common to help diagnose dangling pointer bugs.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie In my daily work, I deal everytimes with _strange_ behavior of my software until I find out that it does exactly what I wrote (but not what I intended to achieve). Hence, I wouldn't judge the term "strange" too hard... ;-)

Comment: `const char * s2 = strndup(s1.c_str(), s1.size())`.  Don't forget to `free(s2)` then.

Comment: Quick mention that OP, as a new user, took the time to provide us with a [mcve], explained their observed and expected behavior, explained their thinking and asked us a specific question. I'd be happy to see more of that kind of question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`s1.c_str()` does not return memory that is independent of `s1`. Changes to `s1` *invalidate* the pointer returned by `s1.c_str()`.

In other words be careful of using `c_str`. In general use it to pass a C string to a function that doesn't accept a C++ string.

Comment: but c_str is called before the new assignment to s1, then how does old assignment to s2 gets changed ?

Comment: @OnkarNMahajan That makes no difference. What is *probably* happening is that cstr returns a pointer to the internal memory that s1 uses. When s1 gets assigned to that memory is freed and so the pointer becaome invalid.

Answer (score 11):

Quoting [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str):

> The pointer obtained from `c_str()` may be invalidated by:
>
> - Calling non-const member functions on the string, excluding operator[], at(), front(), back(), begin(), rbegin(), end() and
>     rend().

By modifying the string, you no longer have a valid pointer.

Also, your premise is wrong. No memory is allocated/free w.r.t. `c_str`. `c_str` and `data` (both identical in C++11) returns a pointer to the underlying storage. It does not *own* the storage. When the storage is changed for whatever reason, your pointer is no longer valid (i.e, it might point to garbage now).

Comment: but c_str is called before the new assignment to s1, then how does old assignment to s2 gets changed ?

Comment: @OnkarNMahajan `s2` is just a pointer (to the contents of `s1`). If `s1` is modified (e.g. by assignment) `s2` becomes invalid. This may mean "everything and nothing". E.g. `s2` still points to the (now modified) contents of `s1`. Or: `s2` points to memory which has been released. (It got dangling which is also called a "wild" pointer.) Assigning `s1` means you _may not_ use `s2`. It doesn't mean you _cannot_ use but doing so is considered as [Undefined Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/1505939).